# Function who counts the number of positive, negative,null numbers of an Array "using pointers"

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

My main problem is to write a C program who uses a `void` function with five arguments: an Array of integer type `T[]`, its size `M`, an integer `P`, another integer `N` and another one `Null_nbr`.
I am NOT TO USE GLOBAL VARIABLES, and to USE POINTERS (because I did it already without Pointers).
The program that I write does not return any Errors or Warnings But it doesn't work !
I'll appreciate it if someone tells me where the issue is in my program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function(int [], int , int *, int *, int *);
int main() {
    int M, t[M] , i, P, N, Null_nbr;    
    printf("enter the size of your array");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    printf("\n enter the array's elements");
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &t[i]);
    }
    function(t, M, &P, &N, &Null_nbr);
}
void function(int t[], int M, int *P, int *N, int *Null_nbr) {
    int i;
    *P=0;
    *N=0;
    *Null_nbr=0;
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++){
        if(t[i] == 0)
            (*Null_nbr)++;
        else if (t[i] < 0)
            (*N)++;
        else
            (*P)++;
    }
    printf("\n P = %d N = %d and  Null=%d", P, N, Null_nbr);        
}
```

Comment: It would be worth running this code through a formatter to clean it up a little bit, or just indent it carefully.

Comment: I'll take a look at the code, but I'll also make a general recommendation that you choose more descriptive variable names in the future.

Comment: What are `P`, `N`, and `Null_nbr` supposed to hold at the end of the program?

Comment: When I compile the code, I get 4 warnings. If you fix those warnings, the code works. If you compile with gcc or clang, be sure to use the `-Wall` option. With microsoft, use `/W3`.

Answer (score 2):

Some programs/compiler don’t allow to define a size of an array like you did (t[M]) because M isn’t a constant value.
Try to write like this.
`int *array, size
array = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int))`.

It should work like this.

Answer (score 1):

If using C99 ...
When `int t[M]` is declared, `M` lacks a specified value.  Leads to *undefined behavior*.

Move declaration after `scanf("%d", &M);`

```
int M, i, P, N, Null_nbr;    
printf("enter the size of your array");
scanf("%d", &M);
assert(M > 0);
int t[M];
```